# GCP: 403 The caller does not have permission

Tags: .net, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

EDIT: I eventually granted edit access to the service account from the sheet's share settings. That let me insert into the sheet. I don't think that is the best solution for my situation, but is an *a* solution.

Any help I would be grateful for. I don't think this is a complicated problem, it's just that I have never used GCP before and am still learning.

I'm trying to write to a Google Sheet using their .NET apis. I want to submit user's feedback to this sheet from within a game I am developing. I'd prefer the process occur without the user undergoing any Google authorization process of their own.

I'm running into this error:

```
GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The caller does not have permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[The caller does not have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

Here's what I've tried so far.

1. Successfully followed Google's guide for reading from a sheet.
2. Create Service Account with Log Writing permissions.
3. Download and use the service account's credentials via `GoogleCredential`.

I have a feeling I just selected the incorrect role, though I'm not sure. I'll keep researching. Again, any help i'd be grateful for.

Comment: Don't answer your question in the question with an edit

Answer (score 2):

You may be better placed using the full OAuth (3-legged-auth) flow for a human user rather than a service account.

See the example here. This uses a human user account and requires the user to approve the code's permission to access their Google Sheets data:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

It's confusing but, while IAM is the modern authorization mechanism used for e.g. Google Cloud Platform services, other Google services don't use IAM but instead use OAuth scopes to define the client's access to API methods.

So, yes, IAM Log Writing is wrong as you're probably referring to the role required for clients to write to Stackdriver Logging.

See Google Sheets' (OAuth) scopes here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

And be aware that the sample code's:

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly };
```

Corresponds to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`

So, you'll need to use: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` and this corresponds to:

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
```

See [Scope](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/90cb4c236ab9342e2287a1250f363fe598fd8d6e/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.cs#L109)

HTH

Comment: In the case that this information changes what you recommend, what I plan to submit to this sheet is people's feedback from within a game I'm making in Unity. I'd prefer the feedback submission operate without any sort of authorization process on the user's end. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Interesting. While I'm a Googler, I work more in GCP than Sheets but, it's an interesting requirement. You're using Sheets as a database which is valid. You don't really want to give your users write access to one of your Sheets though. What you want to do is provide a (REST) endpoint that, when called with the correct values appends a row to your Sheet. This is done manually using Google Forms (in conjunction with Sheets) but I don't know whether you can do this programmatically.  Have a look around.

Comment: I meant to say "Having a look around (for you)" but, I'm interested to hear what others think. For completeness, I'll tell you that this problem is commonly addressed with a simple frontend to a database service like Cloud Firestore|Datastore. BUT I think it's a perfectly reasonably requirement to want to use Google Sheets as your database and, since Forms is also widely used as way to simplify user input to a Google Sheets "database", all we're missing is how to do this programmatically.

Comment: I was able to grant my Service Account's email address edit access through the Sheet's share settings. That let me insert data through the Sheets API.
I agree that a frontend and database would be a common solution, though I thought of Google Sheets as being a simpler option. I will reconsider my approach when am close to releasing the project to others, as that would expose my service account's credentials. Thanks for the input DazWilkin.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should reconsider. I think it's fine to want to submit this data to Sheets. I just don't know how to do it with Sheets and I'm more familiar with using alternatives. Don't let my ignorance dissuade you though. One thing to be mindful of is that you'll need to provide the service account credentials (in your app) to your users so that they can add data to the Sheet. The service account permits anyone to access and edit the data in the Sheet.

Comment: "The service account permits anyone to access and edit the data in the Sheet" Which is why I think I will setup an api with only the possibility to insert info. Thanks for the help.